# MongoDB String type field search match against Array of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

```
Class Tweet
  field :lD,    as: :load_date,           type:Time
  field :t,     as: :text, type:String
end

Tweet.where({:text=>{ $in: ["champ","looser"]},:load_date.gte=>1.month.ago}) #OR
Tweet.where({:text=>{ $all: ["champ","looser"]},:load_date.gte=>1.month.ago}) #AND
```

in and all can be apply over Array not String type field as in my case.
So is it possible to use condition in where clause instead of iterating each element

Answer (score -1):

While the [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) can only be applied to arrays, this is not the case for [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/).

What might be causing your problem is that the first query will only match the text exactly, have you tried something like:

```
Tweet.where({:text=>{ "$in" =>  [/champ/,/looser/]},:load_date.gte=>1.month.ago.utc})
```

Comment: Given the downvote, I assume I have misinterpreted your question. Could you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve in more detail?